# SQL conditional join to multiple tables in one shot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I would like to make conditional join of three tables. Left join table B and if the key is missing then join to table C.

```
+------+--+------+-------------+--+------+-------------+
| A.id |  | B.id | B.OtherFish |  | C.id | C.OtherFish |
+------+--+------+-------------+--+------+-------------+
|    1 |  |    1 | B1          |  |    1 | C1          |
|    2 |  |      |             |  |    2 | C2          |
|    3 |  |    3 | B3          |  |    3 | C3          |
|    4 |  |      |             |  |    4 | C4          |
|    5 |  |    5 | B5          |  |      |             |
|    6 |  |    6 | B6          |  |    6 | C6          |
+------+--+------+-------------+--+------+-------------+
```

There are no matching keys for 2 and 4 in B, and no keys for 5 in C.
Expected results:

```
+------+-----------+
| A.id | OtherFish |
+------+-----------+
|    1 | B1        |
|    2 | C2        |
|    3 | B3        |
|    4 | C4        |
|    5 | B5        |
|    6 | B6        |
+------+-----------+
```

The query I use is:

```
select 
A.id 
,coalesce(B.id,C.id) 
,coalesce(B.OtherFish,C.OtherFish)
from A
left join B
on A.id=B.id
left join C
on A.id=C.id
```

The drawback of the approach is that I have to use coalesce through all the columns I need from different tables. It is annoying if there are hundred columns in the table. **It would be desirable to make a coalesce on the whole aliases** like `coalesce(B,C)`.

Is it possible to make it in one shot like:

```
left join B
on A.id=B.id
left join C
on A.id=(case when B.id is null then C.id end)
```

so that in C.id I would have all good data without making coalesce through all the columns?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What is wrong with COALESCE?

Comment: COALESCE is the way to do that. If you try to do the join conditionally, you may end with a cartesian product, which is worst than use COALESCE.

Comment: Coalesce on every column is annoying and untidy. It would be better if coalesce might be done on the whole aliases like coalesce(B,C).

Comment: Your query is the right way to do this, at least in terms of performance.

Comment: Well, trying to hack your way around this problem most likely will result in some untidy solutions and most likely performance will suffer as well.

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski I'm not sure my query will be slower that his..

Comment: You might be right (will have to see plans), but additionally readability suffers... good luck for other devs to fix this code in 2 years from now on :)

Comment: I agree, harder to understand.. As I said, I don't see anything wrong with coalesce:) @RafalZiolkowski

Comment: @sagi Less is more :) but you are right as well, your query will do the job as well.

Comment: If there are "hundreds of columns" in tables, then that might be your problem, not any use of `COALESCE`. If what you suggested were allowed and meaningful, then that means you've got lots of tables with identical structure, which suggests a violation of normalization rules. In other words: if `B` and `C` are so similar that you could swap them out in joins, why aren't they a single table with a discriminator column?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Actually, A, B, C are in one source table with discriminator columns (many columns). I need to match records by doing self joins.

Comment: If `A`, `B` and `C` are, in fact, the same table, then you can probably write a simpler query with less joins -- if you had a *true* discriminator column, then the `id` values could never overlap between those subsets. You should consider updating your question with your actual scenario, rather than a derived one. It still sounds like your design might be fishy. And I don't mean the presence of `OtherFish`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't see anything wrong with `COALESCE` , you can try using `UNION` , something like this:

```
SELECT a.id,t.OtherFish
FROM A
LEFT JOIN(SELECT b.id,b.otherFish FROM b
          UNION ALL
          SELECT c.id,c.otherFish FROM C 
          where c.id NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM b bb WHERE bb.id = c.id)) t
ON(a.id = t.id)
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Mmm , I don't see why.

Comment: Thanks for this approach. Nevertheless it is disappointing that no simpler solution has been presented. Comparing to math, what I want is to put the alias outside the parentheses to avoid coalescing hundreds of columns.

Comment: Sorry, I doubt there is any other solution. In general, coalesce is the right way to solve this, although this query might be slightly faster. I haven't ever heard of any other way to solve this.. this is not math. @PrzemyslawRemin